# How to Keep Non-Reduced Form of Ratio in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to create a function `rationalSumLowest` that takes an `Int n` and returns a list of ratio numbers that sum to `n`, but only showing the ratio numbers that are already in reduced form. I have attempted to do this by creating the following functions:

```
mergeArrays :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Ratio Int]
mergeArrays [] [] = []
mergeArrays (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x%y] ++ mergeArrays xs ys

rationalSum :: Int -> [Ratio Int]
rationalSum 0 = []
rationalSum 1 = []
rationalSum n = mergeArrays [1..(n-1)] [(n-1), (n-2)..1]

sumLowestBool :: Ratio Int -> Bool
sumLowestBool x
  |(gcd (extractNumerator (x)) (extractDenominator (x)) == 1) = True
  |otherwise = False

rationalSumLowest :: Int -> [Ratio Int]
rationalSumLowest 0 = []
rationalSumLowest 1 = []
rationalSumLowest n = [i | i <- rationalSum (n), sumLowestBool i == True]
```

It should run like this:

```
*Main> rationalSumLowest 5
[1 % 4,2 % 3,3 % 2,4 % 1]
*Main> rationalSumLowest 8
[1 % 7,3 % 5,5 % 3,7 % 1]
*Main> rationalSumLowest 12
[1 % 11,5 % 7,7 % 5,11 % 1]
```

With `rationalSum` running like this:

```
*Main> rationalSum 5
[1 % 4,2 % 3,3 % 2,4 % 1]
*Main> rationalSum 8
[1 % 7,1 % 3,3 % 5,1 % 1,5 % 3,3 % 1,7 % 1]
*Main> rationalSum 1
[]
```

My `rationalSum` function works properly, but my `rationalSumLowest` function does not. It returns the same list as the `rationalSum` function. I know this is because in Haskell, all ratios are automatically reduced and thus my `sumLowestBool` would return `True` for all entries in the list.

My question is: is there a way to keep the non-reduced form of the ratio in the original list so that my `sumLowestBool` function can work properly?

Comment: `mergeArrays = zipWith (%)` (or to go with @coredump's comment, `zipWith (,)`); in any case, always use `x : foo` instead of `[x] ++ foo`.

Comment: Don't store them as ratios, but as tuples

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ratios are reduced, checking that the gcd is 1 is the same as checking that the numerator hasn't changed.

```
import Data.Ratio

rationalSumLowest :: Integer -> [Rational]
rationalSumLowest n =
    [ v
    | i <- [1 .. n-1]
    , let v = i % (n-i)
    , numerator v == i
    ]
```

Comment: That's a good solution, thank you.
I ended up converting them all to tuples, extracting the first and second parts, taking the gcd and checking to see if it was equal to 1. My solution is definitely not as clear and concise as yours.